# How can I change the position of where my Popup menu pops up

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a popup menu in a listview adapter for each item. The menu pops up on the left edge of the screen, how can I change it to be on the right

```
private void showPopupMenu(View v, final App app) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, v);

    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quick_action_menu,
            popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    ...
```

Answer (score 16):

Better late than once =) This is my decision, allows you to set PopupMenu to the specified coordinates. The code is not very good but it works.

```
public void show(Activity activity, float x, float y)
{
    final ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    final View view = new View(context);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(1, 1));
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    root.addView(view);

    view.setX(x);
    view.setY(y);

    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view, Gravity.CENTER);

    popupMenu.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(PopupMenu menu)
        {
            root.removeView(view);
        }
    });

    popupMenu.show();
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution for showing popup on absolute coordinates!

Answer (score 10):

You can change your PopupMenu's position by using the following attributes:
**gravity**, **dropDownHorizontalOffset** and **dropDownVerticalOffset**

First set gravity to Gravity.END

```
popup.setGravity(Gravity.END);
```

Then change your dropdown-offsets by creating a style

```
<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">-4dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">4dp</item>
</style>
```

If you want to overlap the anchor view use

```
parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow"
```

Lastly apply MyPopupMenu to your theme

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
```

Comment: popup.setGravity() requires API level 23

Comment: make sure that you are using backward-compatible Android Support Library, and after import androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu;

Answer (score 2):

You could use [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow) instead. There you have many options for positioning:

- `popupWindow.showAsDropDown(View parent)` Will display below the parent View
- `popupWindow.showAsDropDown(View anchor, int xoff, int yoff)` Will show below the parent View but also applies the offset
- `popupWindow.showAsDropDown(View anchor, int xoff, int yoff, int gravity)` like before but also gravity
- `popupWindow.showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)` popup at any absolute position

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. [As docs say](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html):

> A PopupMenu displays a Menu in a modal popup window anchored to a
>   View. The popup will appear below the anchor view if there is room, or
>   above it if there is not. If the IME is visible the popup will not
>   overlap it until it is touched. Touching outside of the popup will
>   dismiss it.

You may want to try to use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) perhaps, which allows such positioning.

Comment: Just a small addition: Use a PopupWindow and set the desired position in help of showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y).

Comment: Indeed, it was not clear why I sugested PopupWindow. Updated, thanks.

Comment: This makes sense but it contradicts the fact that you can set a gravity (setGravity(int)) which does not make any effect

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListPopupWindow for show List popup menu. There is functions for setting offsets ([ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html)).

Or you can set offsets for your PopupWindow explicitly using this [function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAsDropDown(android.view.View,%20int,%20int))